# Class Library project (C#) - Treat each folder into individual dll file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class, dll

I have a structure like;

-MyProject

```
  -Folder1
    -Class1.cs

  -Folder2
    -Class2.cs
```

What I would like to do is when I compile my solution, all of the folders are output into the separate dll like;

MyProject.Folder1.dll

MyProject.Folder2.dll

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am using VS 2010.

Comment: A project can produce only one DLL.  You will need one *solution* with two projects, one for each DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate each class to separate project.
To add a main project whitch will be referenced to small project

1. Class 1 - Project 1 - Folder1/class1.dll\
2. Class 2 - Project 2 - Folder2/class2.dll